# Como obter informações do trânsito em tempo real, assim como o Waze?

Tags: maps, google-maps-android-api-2, rotas

Consigo habilitar a densidade do trânsito em todo o mapa usando `setTrafficEnabled(true)`, como demonstrado aqui:

[image: mapa demonstrativo]

Gostaria de disponibilizar outras informações (acidentes,blitz, etc..) no GoogleMaps v2 da mesma forma como obtenho a distancia e o tempo estimado para percorrer certo trajeto(utilizando a api directions).

Comment: Entenda que as informações do waze são coletadas utilizando os dados enviados pelos próprio usuários do aplicativo. Você pode ter acesso a mapas e rotas.

Comment: Encontrei apenas uma forma de apresentar a densidade do trânsito em todo o mapa @brasofilo

Comment: Removi os comentários anteriores para deixar limpo para conversas sobre o problema em si (e vou deletar este depois).